# Как убрать небольшую ошибку

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Сегодня спрашивала насчет кода, который бы пропускал безопасные теги. Очень помог lampa, код отлично работает, только, если, допустим, пользователь не заполнил все поля, выводится сообщение о том, что не все поля заполнены и еще вот такой код: string(0)  ""  или string(9) "". string как я понимаю, это строки. Как можно преобразовать код, чтобы это этого не выводилось?

```
$arrays_tags = array(array('<p>', '</p>', '</br>'), array('[p]', '[/p]', '[/br]'));

$text = str_replace($arrays_tags[0], $arrays_tags[1], $text);

$text = htmlspecialchars($text);

$text = str_replace($arrays_tags[1], $arrays_tags[0], $text);

var_dump($text);
```

Comment: У @lampa спросите =)

Comment: @Asen личных сообщений нет.

Comment: Да, не очень удобно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убрать `var_dump($text)`? :)

Comment: Спасибо, можно было в Яндексе посмотреть)